# How to make web site and xamarin project woring with same database

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, model-view-controller, cross-platform

Im a new one in this kind of programming. Im using Visual Studio 2017 and wandering what kind of project to create for xamarin app and web site that are working with same database.

The idea is to create a web site and crossplatform mobile app that are reading and recording in one and the same data base on some host

BR

Comment: You can create separate projects and use one connection string in both.

Comment: You should never have a mobile app try to access a database on a server directly. There are two main approaches to this problem: Create an API on the server that your mobile app can call for database operations, or have a local database (SqLite) and a mechanism that synchronises it with the main database on the server.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher, what is wrong with mobile app which can try to access a database on a server side? I mean, I'm just curious.

Comment: For me it would mainly be security concerns, but there are other issues. Take a look at these: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231500/how-do-i-access-databases-from-a-mobile-device-securely and https://chapmanworld.com/2015/07/02/why-you-shouldnt-connect-your-mobile-application-to-a-database/

Comment: With an API you have everything neatly encapsulated, which improves security, flexibility and maintainability of your server-side code.